# Shadow offset with SwiftUI Shape

Tags: ios, graphics, swiftui

I am trying to draw a circle in SwiftUI using a Shape, Geometry reader and Path, I want a shadow to sit right underneath the circle but the shadow is coming out offset and I can't seem to get it to draw where it should:

[image: shadow offset problem]

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

         return  GeometryReader { geometry in

            VStack(alignment: .center) {
            BackgroundRing()
                .stroke(Color.red, style:  StrokeStyle(lineWidth: geometry.size.width < geometry.size.height ? geometry.size.width / 12.0 :  geometry.size.height / 12))
                .padding()
                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 1.0, x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
            }
         }
    }
}

struct BackgroundRing : Shape {
     func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path: Path = Path()

                let radiusOfRing: CGFloat = (rect.width < rect.height ? rect.width/2 - rect.width / 12 : rect.height/2 - rect.height / 12)
        path.addRelativeArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.width/2, y: rect.height/2),
                                radius: radiusOfRing,
                                startAngle: Angle(radians: 0.0),
                                delta: Angle(radians: Double.pi * 2.0 ))

        return path
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just a shadow?

Comment: Makes no difference - the result is exactly the same. I put the offsets to try and force the location to under the path.

Answer (score 6):

OK So I seem to have managed to fix the problem. There is something going on with the width / heigh that interacts with the code to calculate the location of the shadow - the shadow position seems to come from the frame dimensions rather than the Shape.

Adding

`.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)`

fixes the problem

Additionally, it seems that .shadow automatically sets the default offset to the same value as the radius, so to get a real offset of 0.0 you have to set it relative to the radius, like this:

```
.shadow(radius: 10.0, x: -10.0, y: -10.0)
```

Looks to me like a bug, but this work around solves it:

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

         return  GeometryReader { geometry in

            VStack(alignment: .center) {
            BackgroundRing()
               .stroke(Color.red,
                        style:  StrokeStyle(lineWidth: geometry.size.width < geometry.size.height ? geometry.size.width / 12.0 :  geometry.size.height / 12))
                .shadow(radius: 30.0, x: -30.0, y: -30.0)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            }
         }

    }
}

struct BackgroundRing : Shape {
     func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path: Path = Path()

                let radiusOfRing: CGFloat = (rect.width < rect.height ? rect.width/2 - rect.width / 12 : rect.height/2 - rect.height / 12)
        path.addRelativeArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.width/2, y: rect.height/2), // <- this change solved the problem
                                radius: radiusOfRing,
                                startAngle: Angle(radians: 0.0),
                                delta: Angle(radians: Double.pi * 2.0 ))

        return path
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the same bug with another custom shape. But I have got only a horizontal shift. Your solution is nice. But it didn't help me.